# C : How to use a struct, declared and defined in function A, in another function B

Tags: c

I have a problem in my C code.

In fact, I have declared `struct task_struct *t` under `write_pid` function.
`t` will receive the pid of a specified task. This is the code of the function :

```
static ssize_t write_pid(struct file *pfile, const char __user *buffer,
                                size_t length, loff_t *offset)
{
    char mybuf[10];
    int pid = 0;
    struct task_struct *t;
    struct siginfo info;

    /* read the value from user space */
    if(length > 10)
        return -EINVAL;
    copy_from_user(mybuf, buffer, length);
    sscanf(mybuf, "%d", &pid);
    printk("pid = %d\n", pid);

    /* send the signal */
    memset(&info, 0, sizeof(struct siginfo));
    info.si_signo = SIG_TEST;
    info.si_code = SI_QUEUE;    // this is bit of a trickery: SI_QUEUE is normally used by sigqueue from user space,
                    // and kernel space should use SI_KERNEL. But if SI_KERNEL is used the real_time data 
                    // is not delivered to the user space signal handler function. 
    info.si_int = 260;          //real time signals may have 32 bits of data.

    rcu_read_lock();

    t = pid_task(find_vpid(pid), PIDTYPE_PID);  //find the task_struct associated with this pid

    if(t == NULL){
        printk("no such pid\n");
        rcu_read_unlock();
        return -ENODEV;
    }
    rcu_read_unlock();

    return length;
}
```

Now I want to use `t` in another function as an argument. This is a part of function B code named `read_pid` to more clarify the problem :

```
static ssize_t read_pid(struct file *pfile, char __user *buffer,
                                size_t length, loff_t *offset)
{

    size_t buf_size = 0;
    char *buf = NULL;
    ssize_t total = 0;
    int yalv;
    int ret;
    struct siginfo info;

    ret = send_sig_info(SIG_TEST, &info, t);    //send the signal
    if (ret < 0) {
        printk("error sending signal\n");
        kfree(buf);
        return ret;
                 }
}
```

As you can see, `t` is used as an argument for `send_sig_info` function.

How can I do that ? Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? How did it not work?

Comment: @gaston  Redeclare your functions What is the problem?!

Comment: How / from where are the functions `write_pid` and `read_pid` called?

Comment: This looks like linux kernel programming. I think you are searching for [`struct file::private_data`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/fs.h#L951). If that's the case I think it would be good if you would re-read the chapters in Linux Kernel Programming Guide about character device drivers and maybe read the chapter about [character device drivers on kernel-labs](https://linux-kernel-labs.github.io/master/labs/device_drivers.html#implementation-of-operations).

Comment: when I compile the module it shows me an error : `error: ‘t’ undeclared (first use in this function)
ret = send_sig_info(SIG_TEST, &info, t)`

Comment: Note that neither of this is struct declaration nor struct definition. What you are doing here is defining an *instance* of a struct.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: You can't !

A local variable inside `write_pid` can be passed to functions that is called inside `write_pid` but once `write_pid` returns the local variable no longer exists and therefore can't be used.

If you want to use `t` after `write_pid` has returned, you'll have to make it a variable of the caller of `write_pid` and then pass the address of that variable.

Something like:

```
static ssize_t write_pid(struct file *pfile, const char __user *buffer,
                         size_t length, loff_t *offset,
                         struct task_struct **pt)
 {
     ....
     *pt = pid_task(....)
     ....
 }
```

And call it like:

```
 struct task_struct *t;
 write_pid(............, &t);
```

Now you can pass `t` to `read_pid`

Comment: write_pid and read_pid are the file operations for my linux module. Am I able to call `write_pid(........., &t)` inside `read_pid()` ?